# Is it possible to change the SemanticZoom animation?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm currently using a semantic zoom in an UWP application who look like an Accordion because when I use the Syncfusion Accordion I have an issue with loading due to the ItemsControl inheritence but that's not the question.
I don't like the ZoomIn to ZoomOut animation and I want to know if it's possible to change it.

I find this : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fca2bd49-6727-4a57-8a10-dce26b4388f8/how-to-change-semanticzoom-zoomedout-to-zoomedin-animation-style-?forum=winappswithcsharp
But I wasn't able to make something.

Did someone have an idea ?
If it's not possible then it's no big deal, I will keep it like that.

ps : Sorry if I made english mistakes, I am from France and not very good in English.

Comment: I have tried to edit template. And replace `FadeInThemeAnimation`  with `SwipeBackThemeAnimation` on VisualStateManager element for changing semantic zoom animation. is it  what you want?

Comment: Not really, but thanks you. In the end I create my own Accordion.